# autospec and missing gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cucumber

i've got a strange behavior or autospec. On autospec run i see in console

```
/opt/local/bin/ruby /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.7.3/bin/cucumber --profile autotest-all --format rerun --out /var/folders/xx/xxbiSMYpEjesle1hezvfDU+++TI/-Tmp-/autotest-cucumber20100603-46558-rwbmlp-0 
Missing these required gems:
  cucumber-rails  >= 0.3.1

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.7.249 at /opt/local/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.7 at /Users/alec/.gem/ruby/1.8, /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

But gem is installed

```
alec$ gem search cucumber-rails --local

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

cucumber-rails (0.3.1)
```

what is it? I have installed cucumber with all files in app.

Comment: look for same problem here on SO. It's been solved numerous times!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem. Autotest/autospec is working with development environment, but noth with 'cucumber' environment. Simply add gem requirement to your environment.rb and this problem will be solved.